# VBA to search value then transfer data from one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

a little stuck on this VBA. Havent done VBA in a while so might need to cut me some slack :)

Introduction
Working on a Doc that manages the skills and competencies of several employees in my organisation. All worksheets (with the exception of home have identical layout and cell organisation)

Problem Statement 
I need a VBA that searches one particular cell (B2) for a factory location (i.e. York) if this cell = York, I then need it to copy and paste a list of values (i.e. B2) into a range of cells on another worksheet in the same workbook named "York". I then need this to loop through all worksheets in the doc (kinda like looping through all employees; each employee will have a new worksheet) for the cell value York and copy and paste those cells into the next empty row on the worksheet York. I cannot seem to get the loop to run through, but after writing the code I couldnt even get the copy paste function to work.

Anyone up for the challenge. 
This is my current code. Very poor I know.

```
Sub testv2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range

Set ws = Sheets("MATRIX - MASTER")
"Matrix-master was template copy for all skills"
Set rng = ws.Range("$B$2")

For Each sh In Sheets
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If rng.Value = "York" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Range("B1").Copy
            Sheets("York").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.Range("J6").Paste
        End If
    Next c
 Next sh


End Sub
```

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: As it is you'll just keep making York: J6 equal B1 of each sheet in turn, you're not changing where you want to paste it. It's also good practice to avoid select, copy & paste wherever possible so use `Sheets("York").Range("J6").Value = sh.Range("B1").Value` (presumably changing J6 as you go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you are tring to do.

1. rng is set to one cell of one sheet "$B$2" on "MATRIX - MASTER"
   why do you loop it with for each?
2. I think you ment to write instead of: ActiveWorkbook.Range("J6").Paste

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Copy ' source
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("York").Range("J6").Paste ' target
```

range on the workbook level is used by mamed range.

3. Try to avoid Select... If you must, use Activate.

Comment: I think my main issue is getting it to loop through all the worksheets to look for the value "York" on cell B2. I can create the IF function that will copy cells if the criteria is met I am just having trouble with the loop. Ignore the current VBA I think it is confusing everyone.